# wan to highlight particular positions( which ll have to be fetched from the database) in the list view

Tags: android, listview

```
   List<Integer> values;
   String[] mListContent={"Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wedneday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"};
   Intent myIntent = getIntent();
   iid = myIntent.getExtras().getLong("curr_id");
   values = datasource.getDays(iid);
   ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.simple_selectable_list_item, mListContent); 
   setListAdapter(adapter);
   ListView listView = getListView();
   listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
   for(ii=0; ii<values.size(); ii++)
   {
      listView.setItemChecked(values.get(ii),true);
      Log.i(" values: " + values.get(ii)," ");
   }
```

I have a file named textcolorselector.xml for list, that goes

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="#000" />
<item android:state_checked="true" android:color="#000" />
<item android:state_active="true" android:color="#000" />
<item android:state_selected="true" android:color="#000" />
<item android:color="#888" />   
</selector>
```

say like i have 7 defaut rows in my list and wanna highlight only certain positions

the values from the database are retreived perfectly,in the database i have saved only the position values of the list ie 0,1,...6 for sunday, monday,...saturday respectively,
the problem is extracting values of "values" list is not being changed as set.

Comment: make your question more clear.

Comment: pls do check my question again.

Comment: Create a custom adapter for your listview and inside getView do what you want.

Comment: what should I use inside the getview() to get my result?? thanks in advance

Comment: i also wan to change values to checked and unchecked. will that be possible if I use an adpater??( I initially used array adapter for cutomizing lit with colors, but skipped off I wanna handle the checked and unchecked items directly)

Comment: Look you can do anything with your view once you are able to get it inside the getview method and for that go with this http://stackoverflow.com/a/15402870/1503130

Comment: should I use  curruntButtonClickPosition=position;
?? P.S I'm new to android

Comment: Yes. you need to capture the current position and save it as a static variable to achieve your goal.

Comment: but why isn't my        listView.setItemChecked(values.get(ii),true);
not working?? I can get my job done with this even..

Answer (score 1):

The fact that you setted selector doesn't mean that it will be used for "checking" item. Even more - selector has nothing to do with checked state.

What you need to do, is provide your own view to `ArrayAdapter` that will implement `Checkable` state and provide it own drawable for it.

Comment: its is checkable and I tried deleting few items!! what exactly should I do now?? create an adapter?? and what should I use inside that to get my result?? thanks in advance